# python, generator iterate with one or more items

Tags: python, loops, yaml, generator

I'm using pyyaml, and i'm loading a file.yml

```
stream = open("file.yml", "r")
results = yaml.load_all(stream)
```

results now contains a generator object.

Then, i'm trying to process this:

```
for key, value in results:
    print(key, "->", value)
```

if i have more than one "yaml element" in my file.yml, this works fine. example:

> foo: bar
>
> hello: world

but, if i have a only one "yaml element" in my file.yml, this is not working. example:

> foo: bar

the error is: `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

**i'm using python 3**

how can i solve this? the file.yml can contains 1 or more elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is a list of dictionaries, so instead of iterating over that, you want to be iterating over the dictionaries:

```
for dictionary in results:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print(key, "->", value)
```

So you were trying to assign key to one dictionary, and value to another, because you were unpacking from the list and not the dictionary. `dict.items()` returns a list of tuples with the key in the first position and the value in the other of the tuple.

Comment: why? i always have a dictionary :S

Comment: @fj123x So then why would the ValueError be raised?

Comment: i don't know, see the file.yml example, i always put key: value data in my yml, but when the generator only have 1 element, the ValueError is raising (this not occurs when have more than 1 elemnt)

Comment: @fj123x That doesn't seem right. Do `print(list(results))`. What appears?

Comment: [{'foo': {'bar': 'test', 'hello': 'world'}}]

this is a dict foo: {...}

Comment: can anyone explain why if result seems a dict, i can't directly iterate on it as key -> value?

Comment: @fj123x You're not iterating through it as key/value. `results` is a list, so you're simply assigning key to the first item of the list, and value to the second one

Answer (score 1):

```
results = yaml.load_all(stream)
for doc in results:
    for k, v in doc.items():
        print(k, "->", v)
```